# can't refresh new columns in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I add to my DataGridView 2 new columns but I can't see them.

This my code:

```
dsView = new DataSet();
 SQL = "select Code,Fname,Lname,Age,Gen from MyTbl";
 adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, MyParam.Conn);
 adp.Fill(dsView, "MyTbl");
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dsView.Tables["MyTbl"].DefaultView;
```

Work on C# Visual-studio 2013.

Thanks

Comment: You mean your two columns are missing in `DataGridView`? How did you populate the columns? AutoGenerated or manually added?

Comment: You don't see the columns? or the data in the columns?

Comment: i don't see the columns , if i set to autogenerate=false i see the columns but i cant see the data

Comment: Please be a little more precise. OK, a lot more precise: Which Columns do you add and how do you add them? Do you add them to the DataTable or the DataGridView  and when do you add them?? You didn't show us the code that has the problems, right?

Comment: Am I wrong or do you miss the return value of `adp.Fill(dsView, "MyTbl");` ?